# Python - writing a two byte string as a single byte hex character to a binary file

Tags: python, string, binary, hex, byte

I'm writing a python script that opens a file and reads a two character string value e.g. 32 or 6f. It is then supposed to write that value as a single byte to a binary file as hex e.g. 0x32 or 0x6f.

```
file_in = open('32.xml')
file_contents = file_in.read()
file_in.close()

file_out = open('testfile', 'wb')
file_out.write(file_contents)
file_out.close()
```

In this example, 32.xml is a plain text file that contains the string '32'. But the contents of the testfile output file are '32' instead of 0x32 (or just 2).

I've tried all kinds of variations on the write command. I tried the chr() function but that requires converting the string to an int.

```
file_out.write(chr(int(file_contents)))
```

That ended up writing the hex value of the string, not what I wanted. It also failed as soon as you had a value containing a-f.

I also tried

```
file_out.write('\x' + file_contents)
```

but the python interpreter didn't like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to interpret the original string as a *hexadecimal* integer. Hexadecimal is a base-16 notation, so add `16` to the `int()` call:

```
file_out.write(chr(int(file_contents, 16)))
```

Comment: That's brilliant, exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for the quick solution.